# deprecations chrome when use phaser-framework 2

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

please help explain to me and solve chromium deprecations when using Phaser-framework 2

phaser.min.js:3 [Deprecation] GainNode.gain.value setter smoothing is deprecated and will be removed in M64, around January 2018. Please use setTargetAtTime() instead if smoothing is needed. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5287995770929152 for more details.

phaser.min.js:3 [Deprecation] AudioParam value setter will become equivalent to AudioParam.setValueAtTime() in M65, around March 2018  See https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-value for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Phaser 2 uses some WebAudio features that will be removed and replaced by something different. In this case you can:

1. Patch this by hand by modifying Phaser's source code in your project or
2. Wait for Phaser developers to fix this (if this warning is from Phaser CE) or
3. Try Phaser CE, which I did not used, but may not have these warnings or
4. Try Phaser 3.

If you don't use Phaser's audio system, then you can ignore these warning.